# Installing Ubuntu on newly installed blank SSD (MacBook Unibody)

Tags: system-installation, ssd, macbook, usb-installation

I recently bought a MacBook Unibody from 2010, and would like to install Ubuntu on it (this would be my first time installing or using Ubuntu). Before installing Ubuntu, I plan on removing the hard drive and installing a new SSD. After some research, I believe the plan below would work, but thought it would be best to check as this is my first time installing an SSD and my first time using Ubuntu.

1. Follow the first 3 steps [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#3-create-a-bootable-usb-stick) to create a bootable USB stick.
2. Physically remove the hard drive and install the blank SSD.
3. Power the MacBook on while [holding the Option](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/boot-mode-startup-keys-mac/) (or alt) key to access the boot menu (I'd be a bit concerned about this not working).
4. Follow the rest of the steps in the [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#4-boot-from-usb-flash-drive) to install Ubuntu.

It's a new laptop, so I don't need to worry about losing anything. Does this look like the correct approach for my situation? Is there anything else I need to be aware of / careful about?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please do not ask yes/no or open ended questions. The only correct answer you can get is: try it out and see for yourself. Setting up your system is a personal matter: one big part is the disk layout. Tend to use apache or mysql? /var could use a partition. Just a desktop? Use a single / or / and /home or / and personal partition.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407974/ubuntu-18-installation-on-a-macbook-6-2-mid-2010-has-graphics-and-overheating But since only 4GB of RAM, you may want to consider a lighter flavor than full Ubuntu. I found even Kubuntu worked on my 2006 1.5GB RAM PC. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the install media,
then before anything else, verify that you can boot it (the install media) and that you can see the current HDD from there,
i.e. run it in "Try Ubuntu" -mode.

In Ubuntu, hit <kbd>'Win'</kbd> key *(whatever that correspond to on a MAC; The 'Super' key for Linux)* and type `Disks` (AKA 'gnome-disks' from the terminal/shell/bash)  - it should show you all powered disk devices.

When installing; make sure to select "Install third party software ...". *(This usually includes hardware drivers not available elsewhere that are slightly cumbersome to replace)*.

Opinion: Do not enable encryption unless you have a very specific reason to do so. It generally adds complexity e.g. if you wish to change HDD.

Comment: There is no Win key on a mac. Would this work with the command key?

Comment: Ouch, might be, I'm not a MAC person.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work. I have already used the same procedure on self-built computers, i.e. instead of swapping the SSDs, the hardware was assembled, no big difference. The procedure with swapping the drives and installing Ubuntu has also worked on an old Windows notebook in the past, so I am optimistic that it will also work for you on the Mac.

Don't worry, installing an operating system may seem difficult the first time, but it is very simple and not much more than pressing the right buttons.